# How to set hwc.enable.overlay to 0 in Aosp

Tags: android, android-source

In Android Hardware **video (exoplayer)** was playing **Upside down** but in emulator video was playing proper .
For this scenario I found the fix to set the hwc.enable.overlay to 0 from adb shell .

I need to fix this system property in Aosp rater than running command from terminal.

Comment: PRODUCT_PROPERTY_OVERRIDES += hwc.enable.overlay=0. Add this to your device.mk then build again.

Comment: @yong : Thanks for response ,Could you please specify the path of device.mk

Comment: device/xxxx/device.mk (https://cs.android.com/search?q=device.mk&sq= ). It may be there. If you know a lot about how to build aosp, you can find it there.

Comment: ya Thank you very much Yong .have a nice day .